# Which Eclipse Hadoop Plugin version is the right for Oxygen Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 , and i had installed (Hadoop 1.2.10) in single mode , and Eclipse: Oxygen Release Milestone 4 (4.7.0 M4) ....

Now i want to install Eclipse Plugin For Hadoop to perform MapReduce programs

So is this Plugin (Eclipse Plugin For Hadoop 1.2.1.jar) is the right one ? or the Oxygen  Eclipse must work with another Plugin version?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and won't be finally released until June 2017. Until then plugins from other vendors may not have been tested with Oxygen and might not work.

Comment: Eclipse Neon (4.6.2) is the current Eclipse release.

Comment: I see , so it's better to use Eclipse Luna ?